# GCP AI Platform: Error when creating a custom predictor model version ( trained model Pytorch model + torchvision.transform)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, torchvision, google-ai-platform

Am currently trying to deploy a custom model to AI platform by following ***https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#gcloud_1***. which is based on a combination of the pre-trained model from **'Pytorch'** and '**torchvision.transform'**. Currently, I keep getting below error which happens to be related to 500MB constraint on custom prediction.

**ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to experience errors, please contact support.**

**Setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from pathlib import Path

base = Path(__file__).parent
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [line.strip() for line in open(base/"requirements.txt")]
print(f"\nPackages: {REQUIRED_PACKAGES}\n\n")

# [torch==1.3.0,torchvision==0.4.1, ImageHash==4.2.0
# Pillow==6.2.1,pyvis==0.1.8.2] installs 800mb worth of files

setup(description="Extract features of a image",
      author=,
      name='test',
      version='0.1',
      install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
      project_urls={
                    'Documentation':'https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#tensorflow',
                    'Deploy':'https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#gcloud_1',
                    'Ai_platform troubleshooting':'https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/troubleshooting',
                    'Say Thanks!': 'https://medium.com/searce/deploy-your-own-custom-model-on-gcps-ai-platform- 
 7e42a5721b43',
                    'google Torch wheels':"http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ai-pytorch/readme.txt",
                    'Torch & torchvision wheels':"https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html "
                    },
    python_requires='~=3.7',
    scripts=['predictor.py', 'preproc.py'])
```

**Steps taken:**
Tried adding ‘torch’ and torchvision directly to ‘REQUIRED_PACKAGES’ list in setup.py file in order to provide PyTorch + torchvision as a dependency to be installed while deployment.  I am guessing, Internally Ai platform downloads PyPI package for PyTorch which is +500 MB, this results in the failure of our model deployment. If I just deploy the model with 'torch' only and it seems to be working (of course throws error for not able to find library 'torchvision')

**File size**

- ***pytorch*** (**torch-1.3.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl** about **111MB**)
- ***torchvision*** (**torchvision-0.4.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl** about **46MB**) from ***https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html*** and stored it on GKS.
- The zipped predictor model  file (.tar.gz format) which is the output of  setup.py (**5kb** )
- A trained PyTorch model (size **44MB**)

In total, the model dependencies should be less than 250MB but still, keep getting this error. Have also tried to use the torch and torchvision provided from Google mirrored packages  http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ai-pytorch/readme.txt, but same memory issue persists. AI platform is quite new for us and would like some input from professional’s.

### MORE INFO:

**GCP CLI Input:**

**My environment variable:**

```
BUCKET_NAME= “something”
MODEL_DIR=<>
VERSION_NAME='v6'
MODEL_NAME="something_model"
STAGING_BUCKET=$MODEL_DIR<>
# TORCH_PACKAGE=$MODEL_DIR"package/torch-1.3.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl"
# TORCHVISION_PACKAGE=$MODEL_DIR"package/torchvision-0.4.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl"
TORCH_PACKAGE=<>
TORCHVISION_PACKAGE=<>
CUSTOM_CODE_PATH=$STAGING_BUCKET"imt_ai_predict-0.1.tar.gz"
PREDICTOR_CLASS="predictor.MyPredictor"
REGION=<>
MACHINE_TYPE='mls1-c4-m2'
 
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME   \
--model=$MODEL_NAME   \
--origin=$MODEL_DIR  \
 --runtime-version=2.3  \
 --python-version=3.7   \
--machine-type=$MACHINE_TYPE  \
 --package-uris=$CUSTOM_CODE_PATH,$TORCH_PACKAGE,$TORCHVISION_PACKAGE   \
--prediction-class=$PREDICTOR_CLASS \
```

**GCP CLI Output:**

```
 **[1] global**
 [2] asia-east1
 [3] asia-northeast1
 [4] asia-southeast1
 [5] australia-southeast1
 [6] europe-west1
 [7] europe-west2
 [8] europe-west3
 [9] europe-west4
 [10] northamerica-northeast1
 [11] us-central1
 [12] us-east1
 [13] us-east4
 [14] us-west1
 [15] cancel
Please enter your numeric choice:  1
 
To make this the default region, run `gcloud config set ai_platform/region global`.
 
Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.                                                                                                                                            
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: **Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to experience errors, please contact support.**
```

**My finding:**
Have found articles of people struggling in same ways for PyTorch package and made it work by installing torch wheels on the GCS (https://medium.com/searce/deploy-your-own-custom-model-on-gcps-ai-platform-
7e42a5721b43).
Have tried the same approach with torch and torchvision but no luck till now and waiting response from "cloudml-feedback@google.com cloudml-feedback@google.com". Any help on getting custom  torch_torchvision based custom predictor working on AI platform that will be great.

Comment: I would suggest to deploy models on AI Platform Predictions using custom containers instead of custom prediction routines. Please look at this example > https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/getting-started-pytorch-container.

Comment: Thanks Raj, will look into the custom container. Would you say there are no model memory limitations (<500MB) similar to "custom predictor".

Comment: Could you please try redeploying with a larger machine type, mls1-c4-m4?

Comment: Max memory limitation with Custom Container is 2GB and Custom prediction Routines is 500MB. Custom containers are deployed on n1-* machine types. Here are the supported machine types > https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction#available_machine_types

Comment: Thanks Enrique, will test with "mls1-c4-m4". Although on the official google doc this machine type is not shown also only m1 and m4 type of Mls1 have the custom prediction available.  https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction

Comment: Thanks Raj, 

I did however managed to get a solution to my problem by adding ['torchvision==0.5.0', 'torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.4.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl']  the wheels directly to setup.py  instead calling it from bucket. This way model got deployed with both torch and torchvision. However, in the process of expanding my pre-process steps got stuck with the same memory issue. Guess switching over to container makes sense.

Comment: There are many [examples](https://medium.com/@aftaabzia9/serverless-machine-learning-deployment-with-pytorch-and-google-cloud-f89775773b6b) which mentioned the "mls1-c4-m4" machine type, you can also try with  n1-standard-2 or n1-standard-4 as @raj suggested, this error message occurs when the model server attempts to use over 2gb of allocated memory on the Quad Core CPU (mls1-c4-m2) machine type. This is not necessarily related to the file size of the model, which is within limits, but it is often correlated.

Comment: `mls` machine types have max memory of 2GB and max model size of 500MB which is what I believe causing OOM errors. @EnriqueZetina I don't see `mls1-c4-m4` machine type supported for online predictions. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction

Comment: @ Amrit Kumar Tiwary did you tried with n1-standard-2 or n1-standard-4 machine type, how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this fixed by a combination of few things. I stuck to 4gb CPU MlS1 machine and custom predictor routine (<500MB).

- Install the libraries using setup.py parameter but instead of parsing just the package name and it's version, add correct torch wheel (ideally <100 mb).

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [line.strip() for line in open(base/"requirements.txt")] +\
['torchvision==0.5.0', 'torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.4.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl']
```

- I reduced the steps for preprocessing taken. Couldn't fit in all of them so jsonify your SEND response and GET one from both preproc.py and predictor.py

```
import json
json.dump(your data to send to predictor class)
```

- Import those function from the class of a library that is needed.

```
from torch import zeros,load 
    your code
```

#### [Important]

- Haven't tested different types of serializing object for the trained model, could be a difference there as well to which one (torch.save, pickle, joblib etc) is memory saving.
- Found this link for those whose organization is a partner with GCP might be able to request more quota (am guessing from 500MB to 2GB or so). Didn't had to go in this direction as my issue was resolved and other poped up lol.
  https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/quotas